# Codeigniter Eloquent querying relationships

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, eloquent

I have two tables like this:

`users: users_id | name | users_roles_id`

`users_roles: users_roles_id | roles`

I want to join these tables. I have tried the following:

```
use Elegant\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';

    function getRoles($userId){
        User::join('users_roles', 'users_roles.users_roles_id', '=', 'users.users_roles_id')
            ->select('*')
            ->get();    
    }

    public function user_role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('users_roles','users_roles_id');
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to join these to display it.
Thanks

Comment: Eloquent is part of Laravel.  Use their documentation, you're missing a belongsTo argument since your primary key is not `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this

```
return $this->belongsTo('users_roles', 'users_roles_id');
```

With

```
return $this->belongsTo('users_roles', 'users_roles_id', 'users_id');
```

Read more Eloquent Laravel document for name convenient

Answer (score 0):

i did

```
    class User extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'users';

        function getRoles($userId){
            return $this->where('id', $userId)->join('users_roles', 'users.users_roles_id = users_roles.users_roles_id')->get();  
        }
    }
```

it's working ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You create a

core/MY_Model.php

```
<?php

require_once FCPATH . 'filelocation/Eloquent.php';

class MY_Model extends Eloquent {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Then on the model

models > User_model.php

```
<?php 

class User_model extends MY_Model {
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
}
```